# Windows How to open apps on specific monitor at startup

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am struggling to find a way to automatically run apps specified monitors at startup.
In my case, I have two apps. One app needs to be opened and maximized on the primary screen and the second app needs to be opened on the secondary screen and maximized.

Answer (score 0):

If you p/invoke `ShellExecuteEx` you can set the `SEE_MASK_HMONITOR` flag and the `hMonitor` member. Starting with Windows 8, Explorer sets `STARTUPINFO::hStdOutput` to a monitor handle when starting applications from the taskbar.

Whether or not the application you are starting cares is another question. Anything that remembers its previous position is unlikely to care. If the app creates its first window with `CW_USEDEFAULT` it might work.

Getting something to start maximized is easier. `ProcessStartInfo::WindowStyle`, `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` and `STARTUPINFO` all allow you to force this. The first call to `ShowWindow` will respect the forced show mode...